# Check constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraint

```
check (phone like'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

This is to check the phone number whether it has exactly 10 digits. But I have no idea about placing number as `'[0-9]'`. It seems to be a string. So how can we check numbers inside string?
Can some one explain this query?

The type of column `phone` is `char(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the opposite (does not contain chars not in the 0-9 interval).

```
CHECK (phone NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

Be warned that telephone numbers typically contain also other characters (+,-,.). In that case, you can add allowed symbols to the list:

```
CHECK (phone NOT LIKE '%[^0-9+-.]%')
```

See [`LIKE` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) in the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

This is a regular expression, it´s saying that every value from 0 to 9 is valid and it repeats 10 times. So you have and expression that validates 10 numbers from 0 to 9. 
I leave this link if you eant to learn further about this, is the basis for programming languages and compilers. https://www.rexegg.com/